# 3d widget in XULRunner application

Tags: javascript, 3d, canvas, xulrunner

Does anyone have any experiences trying to include a 3d widget in a XULRunner application? One direction I've been trying is embedding a Java3d applet, but there seem to be a host of problems controlling that applet from the JS of the main application. Another possibility would be if there was some sort of javascript library using the  tag to render 3d, but none that I've seen are particularly mature.

Any recommendations? Or do I just wait until Canvas3d support gets put into the Mozilla core?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [WebGL implementation of latest mozilla builds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL), or use the [Google O3D plugin](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/).